# Create a new variable from existing variables efficiently in python

Tags: python, recode

I am trying to recode variables. I have been able to do this with map, however, I am trying to figure out an efficent way to turn recode multiple values (a, b, c) into a single value. In my example below, I have three different classifications for `Asian` and would like to recode them accordingly.. I tried using booleans but I get the below error.

```
df['Race'] = df['Race'].map({ 
    'Black or African American' : 'Black', 
    'White' : 'White', 
    'Hispanic or Latino': 'Non-White Hispanic', 
    ('Asian' | 'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander' | 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander') : 'Asian/Pacific Islander', 
    ('American Indian or Alaska Native' | 'Other/Mixed') : 'Multiracial/other', 
    'Unspecified' : np.nan
})
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`

Is there an easier yet still efficient way of recoding multiple variables to a single value? It does not have to be map, that is just what I was most familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Dictionary comprehension and unpacking:

```
df['Race'] = df['Race'].map({ 
    'Black or African American' : 'Black', 
    'White' : 'White', 
    'Hispanic or Latino': 'Non-White Hispanic', 
    **{i: 'Asian/Pacific Islander' for i in ('Asian', 'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander', 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander')}, 
    **{i: 'Multiracial/other' for i in ('American Indian or Alaska Native', 'Other/Mixed')}, 
    'Unspecified' : np.nan
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
df['Race'] = df['Race'].map({ 
    'Black or African American' : 'Black', 
    'White' : 'White', 
    'Hispanic or Latino': 'Non-White Hispanic',  
    'Unspecified' : np.nan,
    **dict.fromkeys(['Asian', 'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander', 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander'], 'Asian/Pacific Islander'), 
    **dict.fromkeys(['American Indian or Alaska Native', 'Other/Mixed'], 'Multiracial/other'),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this will do it:

```py
df['Race'] = df['Race'].map({ 
    'Black or African American' : 'Black', 
    'White' : 'White', 
    'Hispanic or Latino': 'Non-White Hispanic', 

    'Asian': 'Asian/Pacific Islander',
    'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander': 'Asian/Pacific Islander',
    'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander': 'Asian/Pacific Islander', 

    'American Indian or Alaska Native': 'Multiracial/other',
    'Other/Mixed': 'Multiracial/other', 

    'Unspecified' : np.nan
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use an apply too improve readability.

```
 race=[
    'Black or African American', 
    'White', 
    'Hispanic or Latino', 
    'Asian', 
    'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander',
    'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander',
    'American Indian or Alaska Native',
    'Other/Mixed',
   'Unspecified'
 ]

 df=pd.DataFrame({'Race':race})

 def lookup(x):
     dictLookup={ 
        'Black or African American' : 'Black', 
        'White' : 'White', 
        'Hispanic or Latino': 'Non-White Hispanic', 
        'Unspecified' : np.nan,
        **{i:'Asian/Pacific Islander' for i in('Asian', 'Asian/Indian/Pacific Islander' , 'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander')},
        **{i:'Multiracial/other' for i in('American Indian or Alaska Native','Alaska Native', 'Other/Mixed')}
     }
     return dictLookup[x]

    df['Race']=df['Race'].apply(lambda x: lookup(x))
                         
    print(df.head(20))
```